# Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment

Tags: perl, syntax-error

I'm having the following complicated error message when I try to execute my script:

```
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at ok.pl line 556, near "$numerocarta,"
Execution of ok.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Line 556 line is:

```
'cardNum' = $numerocarta,
```

The surrounding code is:

```
$agent->submit_form(
form_name => 'form.asp',
with_fields    => {
    'Chapter' => 'Alpha',
    'FirstName' => 'First',
    'LastName' => 'Last',
    'cardNum' = $numerocarta,
    'NAME' => 'Full name',
    'STREET' => 'Street',
    'City' => 'City',
    'State' => 'State',
    'Country' => 'Country',
    'Phone' => '0625410021',
    'Email' => 'email',
    'Amount' => '1',
    'ChapterGiftHonorNem' => 'Alpha',
}
,button => 'B1',
);
```

I'm using WWW::Mechanize.

What am I doing wrong to get this message?

Comment: form.asp seems the page name, not the form name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
'cardNum' = $numerocarta,
```

when you meant to write

```
'cardNum' => $numerocarta,
```

By the way, why so many quotes? `=>` autoquotes barewords on its LHS, so you can use

```
cardNum => $numerocarta,
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!! .. however a got an extra problem.. i got this error now : There is no form with the requested fields... but the form have all this fields.. how to fix please?

Comment: Comments are not the appropriate place to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

```
'cardNum' = $numerocarta,
```

should be

```
'cardNum' => $numerocarta,
```